# How to schedule a script job (macos)

Tags: macos, cron

How can I schedule a script job - once an hour or so...

But I'd like this to be run even if the computer is asleep.

Ideally logged out also - but not a big issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your question:

1) You should not use cron, but rather [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) or one of the scheduler apps that are available out there.

2) If you want to run the script if the user is logged out, you need to run as root or using a [privileged helper](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002589-SW4).

3) Moreover, to have it running while the computer is asleep is something no ordinary scheduler app can achieve. For that, you would have to have access to an API that Apple has not exported for developers to use, i.e., the ability to run code during [Power Nap](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204032). AFAIK, only certain Apple apps are able to run on Power Nap. The only way for you to run such a script is when the computer is powered on again. You can do this by registering for the wake up notification:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {  
     NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(sleepListener(_:)),name: NSWorkspace.didWakeNotification, object: nil)  
}  

@objc private func sleepListener(_ aNotification: Notification) {    
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your response...doesn't help me to solve the problem - but at least I can look somewhere else for a solution.